# How to spy on injected singleton?

Tags: java, unit-testing, dependency-injection, playframework-2.0, singleton

I have a validation method in a model class that gets called from code that I don't have control over. This validation method has parameters that come from dependency injection. One of these parameters is a singleton (`@Singleton`) class.

```
@Singleton
public class ObjValidation {
    @Inject
    public ObjValidation() {
        objsCache = new HashSet<>();
    }

    public boolean exists(String obj) {
        return objsCache.contains(obj) || lookupObj(obj);
    }

    ...
}
```

As you can see this singleton does perform a lookup on a database if the object isn't contained in the cache. While testing this database isn't there and should not be tested. Therefore I'm trying to mock the `exists()` method to return true without being run.

My first thought was, since this is a singleton, if I would inject the singleton into my test case before running it, I would create the singleton instance therefore could `spy` on it.

```
ObjValidation objValidation = spy(app.injector().instanceOf(ObjValidation.class));
doReturn(true).when(objValidation).exists(any());
```

But yes, `spy` only returns a copy and therefore doesn't spy on the instantiated singleton. I would need to replace the singleton instance with the `spy` copy to make it work this way.

How can I do this?

---

Further explanation of the test case:

In my test (method under test is `register()`) I bind a scala.html view form to a model class via the build in functionality of the play framework.

```
public Result register() throws ResultMessageException {
    ...
    Form<Registration> filledRegistrationForm = this.formFactory.form(Registration.class).bindFromRequest();
    ...
}
```

The model has a validation method that has parameters that get injected as described in the play documentation: https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.6.x/JavaForms#Custom-class-level-constraints-with-DI-support

```
@ValidateWithDI
public class Registration implements ValidatableWithDI<ValidationError> {

    @Required
    private String obj;

    @Override
    public ValidationError validate(ObjValidation objValidation) {
        if (!objValidation.exists(obj)) {
            return new ValidationError("obj");
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

This validation method gets called by the framework while binding the form.

Comment: pass in the spy explicitly. During unittesting you should not use the DI framework (only).

Comment: What do you mean with "pass in"? I can't pass it in since I don't have any control over the caller who is passing in the dependency injected singleton.

Comment: In you unit test you have **full control** over the dependencies passed into your unit under test.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you mean or if we misunderstand each other. Could you explain further?

Comment: you can refer here: https://nearsoft.com/blog/annotation-magic-with-mockito-injectmocks/

Comment: @TimothyTruckle I don't think you did understand the problem that I'm trying to solve. I added more detail on my test case.

Comment: The annotation Spy with InjectMocks will help you inject the instance created by Spy into your target test object. I still didn't see the point of this question @Spehouet